# Handling exception from Jedis pipeline

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Suppose my Jedis pipeline has following redis commands:

```
<A,B,C,D>
```

This pipe is executed by `pipeline.syncAndReturnAll()`. Now suppose command **'C'** gave an exception (bg fail in my case). Here Jedis instead of throwing exception back at **syncAndReturnAll** put exception object for **C** in the result **List of Objects**.

I need to discard whole pipe, when there is an exception anywhere in the pipe (Atomic). Is there any way to achieve it? Isn't pipeline group-atomic with default arguments?

Comment: Did you check lua support in redis? Build a custom lua script to be executed against redis, then if something fails, you will get a lua exception (that you can also catch if wanted).

Comment: So instead of pipeline use lua? I could do this - save current radis values of A,B... and put them back in Redis if caught any exception at C. Lua support in Redis is cool!

But see, this is an overkill for me, pipeline Java should be atomic? It is already in python (redis.py). My current code is all in Java, so it provides better integration by calling pipeline in Java rather than generating lua from code and then uploading and executing.